# Statically initialized struct self-reference

Tags: c, struct

I have a simple structure that is defined like so:

```
typedef struct { 
    int index;
    double* arrayToRead;
} my_struct;
```

I want to initialize an array of structures so they become something like this:

```
double decimals[2] = {1.0, 2.0};

my_struct[2] = {
    {0, &decimals[0]},
    {1, &decimals[1]}
};
```

I have to initialize this array of structs statically.

Can I initialize it statically while referring to a previously defined member, like so:

```
my_struct[2] = {
    {0, &decimals[index]},
    {1, &decimals[index]}
};
```

Where "index" refers to the value for index defined to the left of "decimals"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.<sup>*</sup>

If you're desperate, you could always devise a macro for this purpose:

```
#define DEFINE_ELEMENT(i) {(i), &decimals[(i)]}
my_struct m[2] = {
    DEFINE_ELEMENT(0),
    DEFINE_ELEMENT(1)
};
#undef DEFINE_ELEMENT
```

---

<sub>* Or "yes", as @Jens points out in his answer, for C99.</sub>

Comment: close, but the answwer is yes, see my answer :)

Comment: @Jens: I hadn't thought of that (so +1 for your interesting answer).  Technically, it's still "no", though, as it's not the syntax the OP had in mind...

Answer (score 7):

If you have a modern C compiler (aka C99) you can use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) for code unrolling. Something like

```
#define INIT_ELEMENT(NAME, X, I) [I] = { \
  .index = I,                            \
  .arraytoread = &decimals[I]            \
}
#define INIT_ELEMENTS(N) P99_FOR(, N, P00_SEQ, INIT_ELEMENT, P99_DUPL(N,))
```

and then

```
my_struct A[] = { INIT_ELEMENTS(2) };
```

should expand to an initializer of your liking.

(Here the first macro defines the code that is to be repeated, using only `I` from its arguments, the index of the invocation. In the second macro `P00_SEQ` means that this is separated by comma.)

Comment: Oooo...I hadn't heard of that. Nifty.

Comment: +1, but anyway, what's the advantage of all this over saving a macro in vim, applying it n times and ending up with something readable?

Comment: @ninjalj, the day you change the `2` into `42` ?

Comment: @JensGustedt: I thought the problem was generating an array from some initial index to some terminating index, and not having to write each index twice? I mean, the P99_FOR part.

Comment: @ninjalj, my understanding is that the OP wanted to initialize by a series of something like `{i, &decimals[i]}`, such that the index field is initialized to the current number and the pointer value is taken as the ith element of the `decimals` array. What I have given here is just the same with designated initializer syntax, no?

Comment: Sure, it's only that I find pure C99 syntax (as in Oli's answer) much more readable, and you can always use an editor macro for the repetition, instead of the P99_FOR. Just a matter of tastes, I guess (I'm not used to P99).

Comment: @ninjalj, I see your point, and certainly I'd have to work to have a macro that is easier to read and use. For the usefulness, you'd really have to imagine that the `2` is a define given on the compiler commandline with `-DALEN=42` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What's that in the sky? *It's a bird!* **No, it's a plane!** ***No, it's Code-Generation Man!***

[image]

Or--with tongue removed from cheek--I don't know that there is a built in feature that supports this, but you can always use an external tool to write the initialization code for you.

---

Basically you write a script in some convenient language that output a c code fragment defining the structure and declaring the variable with the long-hand intialization, then use the c-preprocessor's `#include` feature to drag that generated file into you code.

You'll want to make the build manager aware of this need. In make it would look something like

```
cfile.o: cfile.c mystruct.c

my_struct.c:
        awk -f generate_my_struct.awk > my_struct.c
```

Comment: There's a place for snark, and this isn't it.  The snark is highly distracting from the useful content of your answer ("no, use code generation").

Comment: Er...@Adam, it was meant to be a real suggestion. Not anyone's first choice, of course, but a perfectly valid solution to the problem. Perhaps my humor is out of calibration today.

Comment: I agree that it's a perfectly valid solution to the problem; I disagree with the way you presented it.

Comment: Err, what?  Where did that come from?  In any case, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to give a name for your new array

```
my_struct my_array[2] = {
  {0, &decimals[my_array[0].index]},
  {1, &decimals[my_array[1].index]}
};
```